# split fields using awk or sed

Tags: sed, awk, split

I have a file with a column as shown below,

```
 chr1 412573  .   A   C 2754.00      .  AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DP=59;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.0000;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=59.22;M  
 Q0=0;QD=35.08;SB=-5.570e+02;resource.EFF=NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|gCg/gTg|A124V
|RBFA|protein_coding|CODING|ENSCAFT00000037436|5)
```

I want to split and extract data in 8th column as shown below,

```
chr1 412573  .   A   C 2754.00      .  59    59.22    NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING    MODERATE    MISSENSE    gCg/gTg    A124V    RBFA   protein_coding    CODING    ENSCAFT00000037436    5
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
awk '/DP=/ || /MQ=/ || /EFF=/ {gsub("[\\|()]", "\t"); print $2}' RS=';' ORS='\t' FS='='
```

Result

```
59  59.22   NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING   MODERATE    MISSENSE    gCg/gTg A124V   RBFA    protein_coding  CODING  ENSCAFT00000037436  5
```

Comment: The above code splits in the way which you have shown only for the first row. But, from the second row it is printing AC as the first column followed by the remaining data. Could you help why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `awk`:

Content of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
        FS = ";"
}

{
        str = $NF
        sub( /^[^=]*=/, "", str )
        gsub( /[|()]/, "\t", str )
        print str
}
```

Run it like:

```
awk -f script.awk infile
```

That yields:

```
NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING   MODERATE    MISSENSE    gCg/gTg A124V   RBFA    protein_coding  CODING  ENSCAFT00000037436  5
```

Comment: For example, if the corresponding data is in 8th column, How do i specify in the script to work on 8th column?

Comment: @user1779730: `$NF` means last field, to select the 8th, use `$8` instead.